# Why might chrome interfere with port 8000 in localhost?

Tags: laravel, google-chrome

I have a laravel project which is facing issues when trying to be run on chrome. When I try to run php artisan serve, chrome keeps on loading and reloading the site and the git shell shows it is constantly loading the css and js files. This issue is non existent in firefox or edge. It also provides no error output or logs.

My colleagues suggested simply uninstalling chrome or using other browsers, but I am comfortable with chrome and do not want to lose the cache; and multiple chrome profiles are used in this device so sync will not be perfect.

What I tried:

1. No, this is not a skype issue, already uninstalled that.
2. Using another port is not an option because there are APIS that has whitelisted only 8000 as a valid url and whitelisting other ports is more hassle than my colleagues are willing to go through.
3. Checked for other programs using this port and that is not the issue.

TLDR: What might cause chrome to interfere with port 8000 in a laravel project and how might I resolve it without brute forcing like reinstalling or switching platforms?
N.B: Chrome: Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10, XAMPP 3.2.3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Do you have any proxy defined in Chrome?

Comment: Could any installed extension/addon cause this? Have you tried running without addons? (I don't think Skype uses port 8000, even if it did it would not work in other browsers too)

Comment: @ewong Thank you. No, I do not have any proxies set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be an extension in chrome since the issue does not exist in incognito mode. Thanks to @brombeer for pointing the fact out.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file and see what program is using port 8000 some other must be using that port that's why its not running
Then you can see all used ports and here we see that the 80port is already used by System.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTGY7.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjOOr.png

Find location of xampp-control.exe file (probably in **C:\xampp**)
Create a file **XAMPP.INI** in that directory (so **XAMPP.ini** and xampp-control.exe are in the same directory) Put following lines in the XAMPP.INI file: **apache = 8012**

Comment: "_This issue is non existent in firefox or edge_" Why does it work in these browsers then?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but as I said, I already checked if the port was being used by any other program. I did check the netstat as suggested and also from command prompt and task manager. There really is nothing there and if there was, firefox and edge would also cause issues, which they do not.